# iOS chart not building

Tags: ios, swift, charts, ios-charts

I have followed a 3rd party tutorial on IOS Charts (How to Use iOS Charts API to Create Beautiful Charts in Swift)

[IOS charts tutorial](https://www.appcoda.com/ios-charts-api-tutorial/)

and everything works fine for the demo app and also creating a chart app from scratch.

However I also have a working app and I am trying to add a graph to it but when I add the embedded binaries to my working app, my project will no longer build and I get the error message...

> clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

Does anyone have any ideas why this is happening and how to fix it?

Thanks

Comment: Does it worked?

Comment: Hi Hasya, Thanks for your help. I tried your solution but it did not work. In the end I found the problem. I had convert my working app to Swift 3 via edit > convert > To current swift syntax in order to use IOS charts. In fact I have just finished coding the chart this weekend and it works a treat.

Comment: Good, have a happy coding.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had convert my working app to Swift 3 via edit > convert > To current swift syntax in order to use IOS charts. It now works perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

Well I have integrated iOS chart successfully and drafted line chart.

[Please download project.](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B7ooURy3zGWKdlVNQWVkTjZpXzg/view?usp=sharing)

[image]

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    
  @IBOutlet weak var lineChartView: LineChartView!
    
        override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
        
        let months = ["1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7"]
        let unitsSold = [5.0, 1.0, 2.0, 9.0, 15.0, 3.0, 4.0]

        
        setChart(months, values: unitsSold)
        
    }

    
    func setChart(dataPoints: [String], values: [Double]) {
        
        var dataEntries: [ChartDataEntry] = []
        
        for i in 0..<dataPoints.count {
            if !values[i].isZero {
                let dataEntry = ChartDataEntry(value: Double(values[i]), xIndex: i)
                dataEntries.append(dataEntry)
            }
        }
        
        var colors: [UIColor] = []
        
        for i in 0..<dataPoints.count {
            let red = Double(arc4random_uniform(256))
            let green = Double(arc4random_uniform(256))
            let blue = Double(arc4random_uniform(256))
            
            let color = UIColor(red: CGFloat(red/255), green: CGFloat(green/255), blue: CGFloat(blue/255), alpha: 1)
            colors.append(color)
        }
        
       
        
        
        let lineChartDataSet = LineChartDataSet(yVals: dataEntries, label: "")
        lineChartDataSet.drawValuesEnabled = false
                        lineChartDataSet.drawFilledEnabled = false

        lineChartDataSet.cubicIntensity = 1.0
        
        let lineChartData = LineChartData(xVals: dataPoints, dataSet: lineChartDataSet)
        
        
        lineChartView.data = lineChartData

        lineChartView.leftAxis.enabled = false

        lineChartView.xAxis.labelPosition = .Bottom

        
    }
    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

   
}
```

Few check are there for setup as below.

(1) Bitcode
[image]

(2) Compile sources
[image]

(3) Valid architecture
[image]

Hope this will help you to integrate it properly.